# PostgreSQL driver "Unable to load class "

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I want to connect my application with database. I'm using eclipse. JDBC driver added to class path and after compilation I have a message eror:

```
Could not load requested class : com.postgresql.Driver
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml looks like:

```
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.postgresql.Driver</property>

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
```

Dou You have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classname is `org.postgresql.Driver` (not `com.`)

For details see the manual: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/load.html